# jScript and CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

I would like to use a script that makes my CSS property change from display:none to display:initial.

Here is the script I have written:

```
    function setVisibleLP(){

    if(document.getElementById('arrow_first').style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementById('arrow_first').style.display = "initial";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('arrow_first').style.display = "none";
        }
    if(document.getElementById('arrow_second').style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementById('arrow_second').style.display = "initial";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('arrow_second').style.display = "none";}
}
```

In the CSS file both ID display property is set to NONE by default. To run the script I have a button input inside my HTML that activates the script with the onclick event.

The problem : Function not working. It is being called on HTML by an input button with an onclick event like this:

```
<input type="button" value="show me around" onclick="setVisibleLP()" />
```

HTML idS:

```
    <a id="goPos1" href="#"><img id="arrow_first" src="img/icons/arrow1.png" /></a>
    <a id="goPos2" href="#"><img id="arrow_second" src="img/icons/arrow1.png" /></a>
```

CSS for those ids above:

```
#arrow_first{
    display: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5%;
    left: 9%;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform:rotate(-13deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-13deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-13deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
#arrow_second{
    display: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11%;
    left: 74%;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform:rotate(-29deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-29deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-29deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the issue is ?

Comment: Lets assume it's the syntax errors! You have parenthesis and curlybraces out of order !

Comment: can you put both html and js into jsfiddle?

Comment: better if you put your both html and all related js code.

Comment: `initial` is also not a valid value for the `display` property...: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: @AndréDion - Uhm -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: on W3C I found "initial" to be the default value of display property but anyway I also tried to put it to be BLOCK, just in case. Ain't working either.

Changed the code to show you exactly how im dealing with it.

Comment: yet the html is not enough, put the main html element which is to be display none or intial.

Comment: @adeneo Well...TIL! Although it's worth noting that `initial` isn't supported by IE.

Comment: Works for me though -> http://jsfiddle.net/6NEk7/

Comment: Still works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/6NEk7/1/

Comment: Yeah the code is fine.

Comment: @adeneo Maybe its not working for me because Im asking inline elements (img) to be displayed, instead of block elements (like div)

Dunno XD

Comment: So it appears Im as dumb as a dumb (yeah, that much). I couldn't click on the button because it wasn't "z-index(ed)" enought. Changed it to be on top and now everything works. Thank you very much, all of you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify your code:

```
function toggleVisible(el) {
    el.style.display = el.style.display=="none" ? "initial" : "none";
}
function setVisibleLP(){
    toggleVisible(document.getElementById('arrow_first'));
    toggleVisible(document.getElementById('arrow_second'));
}
```

Then, the problem may be that `style` property only contains inline styles, not the ones defined in stylesheets. Therefore, you may have to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

```
function toggleVisible(el) {
    el.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).display == "none"
      ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

Another possible problem could be that you have `!important` styles which override inline ones. Then, use

```
function toggleVisible(el) {
    el.style.setProperty(
        "display",
        window.getComputedStyle(el, null).display == "none"  ? "initial" : "none",
        "important"
    );
}
```